# PostgreSQL is not working after installing Postgres-XC

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, ubuntu, psql, postgres-xc

I am using PostgreSQL 9.3 on Ubuntu 17. This set up was working fine, but it stopped working after installing Postgres-XC.

I tried uninstalling Postgres-XC and reverting back the data directory to the
default position. It didn't work and I'm getting

> `psql: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist.`

Any help will be appreciated.